# How to properly stop Meteor Tracker.autorun?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have the following:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  var computation = Tracker.autorun(function() {
    var currentChapter;
    currentChapter = Chapters.findOne({
      _id: currentChapterId
    });
    if (currentChapter) {
      if (currentChapter.title) {
        $("#input-title").val(currentChapter.title);
      } else {
        $("#input-title").val("");
      }
      if (currentChapter.content) {
        $("#input-content").html(currentChapter.content);
      } else {
        $("#input-content").html("");
      }
    }
    return computation.stop();
  });
});
```

Right now I get:

> Exception from Tracker afterFlush function: Cannot call method 'stop'
>   of undefined TypeError: Cannot call method 'stop' of undefined

What I want to do is to stop the computation once `currentChapter` is true. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would use the [observe method](http://docs.meteor.com/#observe) on the cursor instead of using `Tracker.autorun` in your case.

Comment: @Peppe L-G Why would you use observe instead?

Comment: I would use the observe callback mostly to make the code more readable, but I think it would also execute faster and be a little bit smaller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things:

1 - Your autorun function gets a handle to the computation passed to it, so you can stop it like so:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  var computation = Tracker.autorun(function(thisComp) {
    var currentChapter;
    currentChapter = Chapters.findOne({
      _id: currentChapterId
    });
    if (currentChapter) {
      if (currentChapter.title) {
        $("#input-title").val(currentChapter.title);
      } else {
        $("#input-title").val("");
      }
      if (currentChapter.content) {
        $("#input-content").html(currentChapter.content);
      } else {
        $("#input-content").html("");
      }
      thisComp.stop();
    }
  });
});
```

2 - In your code, the computation would be stopped at the end of the first run regardless - you should be stopping it within the `if (currentChapter)` block.

Comment: The return value from `Tracket.aurotun` should be the same as your `thisComp` parameter.

Comment: Sorry, Peppe L-G, I don't understand - could you explain?

Comment: @PeppeL-G the `thisComp` comes from the first param of the `function`, I think Meteor added this in too (as well as the return value)

Comment: @Akshat, I'm not saying the suggested solution shouldn't work, I'm just saying that it shouldn't make any difference using the computation object via the parameter instead of via the return value. However, since changing it seems to have solved the problem, it makes me wonder if there isn't is a bug some where. Or have I misunderstand something?

Comment: @PeppeL-G when the function runs the initial time, `computation` would not have been assigned a value till the method finishes running. I think therefore that the callback of `Tracker.autorun` is blocking

Comment: @Peppe L-G The original code is in CoffeScript and there are not explicit `returns`. I'm not sure but I think CS adds them automatically. Maybe that's the cause?

Comment: @Peppe L-G Or maybe I wasn't clear in what I wanted to accomplish. What I wanted was for the code to stop running every time I type in the `contenteditable` div and the collection is updated.

Comment: @alexchenco, I recommend you to start a new question where you fully explain your problem. The problem explained in this question is now solved.

Comment: Yes it is. I was just explaining to you what might be the cause of your confusion.